# How can I make an undefined parameter not required?

Tags: typescript

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkBGArKBeKBvAsAKCigEMAuKAVwDsATCAMwEtKJqBufQpMy8gWyQgAndgSgBjMgGdggpgHMRAX3z4A9KqgQAHpDHAWZMUQA2xgBQAiIhYCUAGnEnzFpBYcBGe49OWxbqBYAzLYqeHRUegwA9pTexgA8ANKaWvo0klAA1hAgUXSw8MhomNm5+XCQRQB8ZqVkiQ5gRIJEvGQViKgA2okAujbYocp4+EY+VrZQ6hQAFlBRMwCEo06Wrh42rHFrk9NyUVHUK+N+DhOb2xZ+A3sHRyN400jkwFC8RJnyUAyvUWDA0UoJig1CiEEklFeAHcooJMpofjMhPhwpRIjE4gAmJIpNLUDKlPIFSqoDBZHJEjrVWo5eqNZqtAD87UK3T6A1wD2Gx2MmMs1huGn2hx5fJcti200oUVewuoUDMkggYhi8qaLV4UEkMyi5GM8oEUEEEAAjuQGMbqDZRb5dhoTJIolBpbK7kA)

I'm trying to make undefined values be optional, while non-optional values are optional. My perfect example would be:

```
type TypeObj = {
  a: undefined;
  b: number;
  c: string;
}

call("a"); call("b", 1); call("c", "3"); // should work
call("b", "a"); call("c", 3) // shouldn't work
call("b"); call("c") // also shouldn't work
```

but my current approach (with the second parameter being optional) allows `call`ing b and c without the second parameter, which I do not want.

```
function call<K extends keyof TypeObj = keyof TypeObj>(key: K, param?: TypeObj[K]) {

}

call("a"); call("b", 1); call("c", "3"); // works (good)
call("b", "a"); call("c", 3) // doesn't work (good)
call("b"); call("c") // works (don't want that)
```

Comment: I don't understand why `T` is generic in this code; shouldn't you just use `TypeObj`?  Is there anything else it can be?  I'm hoping you can pare this down to a [mre], so unless `T` being generic is necessary and you can demonstrate why, I suggest you remove it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMMJrm)

Comment: I do need that for my own code, but it's useless for the question. I'll edit it to remove it as long as it doesn't tarnish the original need.

Comment: Hopefully in your own code you're also passing a value of type `T`... if you need to manually specify `T` but have the compiler infer `K` you'll have a bad time.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6500W) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining.  If not, please let me know what's wrong and [edit] the question to demonstrate failed use cases.

Comment: It does indeed!

Comment: You're sure, right?  I don't want to write up an answer and then get the "oh there's one little thing that doesn't work about this" comment which requires a complete refactoring to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing essentially requires `call()` to have multiple call signatures.
Traditionally this would need you to make `call()` an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), but you can also do it by having the function accept a [tuple-typed rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types).

Here's one approach:

```
type OptionalIfUndefined<T> =
  undefined extends T ? [param?: T] : [param: T];

function call<K extends keyof TypeObj>(
  key: K, ...[param]: OptionalIfUndefined<TypeObj[K]>
) {
  const _param = param as TypeObj[K]; // <-- might need this
}
```

The `OptionalIfUndefined<T>` type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks if `undefined` is assignable to `T`.  If so, it evaluates to a single-element [tuple with an optional element of type `T`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types); otherwise, it evaluates to a single-element tuple with a *required* element of type `T`.

Then `call()` is given a rest parameter of type `OptionalIfUndefined<TypeObj[K]>`.  We use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) so that `param` is a variable name holding the single element, since that's all we really want (the actual array holding it isn't useful to us).

In your example you didn't do anything inside the implementation of `call()`, but if you were expecting `param` to be known as type `TypeObj[K]` you'll be disappointed.  A generic conditional type is essentially opaque to the compiler, so it doesn't know that `typeof param` will be anything narrower than `TypeObj[K] | undefined`.  You'll need to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) it like `const _param = param as TypeObj[K]` and then use `_param` instead of `param` (or swap the names if you want) if you need such functionality.

Well, let's make sure it works:

```
call("a") // okay
call("a", undefined) // okay
call("b", 1); // okay
call("b") // error
call("c", "a"); // okay
call("c") // error
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEHkBGArKBeKBvAsAKCigEMAuKAVwDsATCAMwEtKJqBufQpMy8gWyQgAndgSgBjMgGdggpgHMRAX3z5QkKAjDAGAe0pEANgEk6AVRr0mLADwwAfBg4ULjZtSgQAHsAg1JsKAB+KABtMCJBIl5AshgAXSgyMIio2LiRfDoqMW09cUMDawBpD29fan8AawgQHTpYeGQUOwAKJ2qQMiKAGigAOgHkyN44sk1c-WMzFytqW0bUEKK4u3wASmwnMT1pKAB9cOGMKEOo4n84SCal9KgAejuoawBaZ6heBjkAC2AoZhYoMAvgxJPhlHgVHgxAUWgAiIiwjYPKA6SpEED4aEGAxwhG9Ki0VwsJGPVHozEw2FIWG9ACMa1Y91JaIxUMp1JJHkEgh0ggp2LhYhpUHhiMZyLJrKxONhQs5Qh5fIheCAA)